# Matching groups with lookahead expression

Tags: java, regex, scala

I have problem with matching groups that contain lookahead expression. I don't know why this expressions doesn't work:

```
"""((?<=^)(.*)(?=\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s%))((?<=[\w:]\s)(\w+)(?=\s[cr]))"""
```

When I compile them separately, for example:

```
"""(?<=^)(.*)(?=\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s%)"""
```

I get the correct result

My sample text:

```
May  5 23:00:01 10.14.3.10 %ASA-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection
```

Expressions have been checked with this tool: http://regex-testdrive.com/en/dotest

My Scala code:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex
val text = "May  5 23:00:01 10.14.3.10 %ASA-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection"
val regex = new Regex("""((?<=^)(.*)(?=\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s%))((?<=[\w:]\s)(\w+)(?=\s[cr]))""")
val result = regex.findAllIn(text)
```

Does anyone know solution of this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to get `May  5 23:00:01` and `UDP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Multiple matching

You may fix the pattern as

```
^.*?(?=\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s%)|(?<=[\w:]\s)\w+(?=\s[cr])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ryp2kl/2). The main point is to introduce the `|` alternation operator to match either of the 2 subpatterns. Note you do not need to put the `^` start of string anchor into a lookbehind, as `^` is already a zero-width assertion. Also, there are too many groupings that you do not seem to use any way. Also, to match a literal dot you need to escape it (`.` -> `\.`).

To obtain the multiple matches, you may use the following code snippet:

```
val text = "May  5 23:00:01 10.14.3.10 %ASA-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection"
val regex = """^.*?(?=\s\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\s%)|(?<=[\w:]\s)\w+(?=\s[cr])""".r
val result = regex.findAllIn(text)
result.foreach { x => println(x) }
// => May  5 23:00:01
//    UDP
```

See the [Scala online demo](https://ideone.com/nvdILB).

Note that once a pattern is used with `.FindAllIn`, it is not anchored by default, so you will get all the matches there are in the input string.

## Capturing groups

Another approach you may use is *matching* the whole line while *capturing* the necessary bits with capturing groups:

```
val text = "May  5 23:00:01 10.14.3.10 %ASA-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection"
val regex = """^(.*?)\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s%.*[\w:]\s+(\w+)\s+[cr].*""".r
val results = text match {
  case regex(date, protocol) => Array(date, protocol)
  case _ => Array[String]()
}
// Demo printing
results.foreach { m =>
  println(m)
}
```

See [another Scala demo](https://ideone.com/9u0IdS). Since `match` requires a full string match, `.*` is added at the end of the pattern, and only relevant pairs of unescaped `(...)` are kept in the pattern. See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/3LLesX/1).

Answer (score 0):

your matches are not next to each other,
try this:

```
"""((?<=^)(.*)(?=\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s%)).*((?<=[\w:]\s)(\w+)(?=\s[cr]))"""
```

I just added the .* between them, it works on the link you sent :)